# How to find the range of the parameters using the basic feasible solutions I have found?

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

> Given the problem: 
> maximize $a_1x_1+a_2x_2$ 
> s.t.
>  $2x_1-x_2\ge 2$ 
> $x_1+x_2\le 4$ 
> $x_1,x_2\ge 0$
>
> a) Given that $a_1=1,a_2=2$, solve the problem graphically. 
> b) Find all the basic feasible solutions of the problem. 
> c) Using the basic feasible solutions you found, find a range for the values of $a_1,a_2$ such that the solution you've found is still optimal.

I have solved (a) and (b), I've found that the optimal solution is $(2,2)$ with optimal value $6$, and found all the basic feasible solutions, and saw that they are the vertices of the feasible area in my graph in (a). 

What I don't understand is how to solve (c), I can understand graphically that I could change the parameters until $(2,2)$ is not an optimal solution anymore, but I can't understand how do I use the basic feasible solutions I've found to do that?
What does knowing the basic feasible solutions tell me about the parameters? Is it just them being the vertices? 
I feel lost, and would appreciate any help. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any values of $a_1$ and $a_2$, you know that the optimal solution will be a basic feasible solution (BFS). So one way to answer the question is to write the object value of each BFS as a function of $a_1$ and $a_2$, compare those expressions, and figure out for what values of $a_1$ and $a_2$ the solution you found has objective value at least as large as that of any other BFS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just to make sure I understood your explanation correctly, if I could write the object value of each BFS I found, I guess I would just substitute them in my object function, I had $(1,0)$,$(4,0)$,$(2,2)$,so I would get $a_1$, $4a_1$, $2a_1+2a_2$. And now I should do $2a_1+2a_2 \ge a_1$ and $2a_1+2a_2 \ge 4a_1$ and that's it?

Comment: Yes. Since you are operating in two dimensions, you could solve the inequalities by graphing the respective lines.